# How to make this breed of resizable vertical divider for two divs?

Tags: css, html

I want to know what the best way is to have two divs (unless this is using some table?) that are side by side, separated by a vertical divider.

[image]

Notice how when the handler is resized, the elements appear to be resizing to accomodate the new width:
[image]

Notice how when the handler is further resized, it appears to overlap the elements on the sidebar exposing just a little bit of the text. If the user continues to resize to the left, it covers up all the text.

[image]

How to create this with css/html5/maybe some javascript? Examples would be great of (divs? or whatever basic elements with text or anything necessary to illustrate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [splitter plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/) for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).